# Merge an array with specified values into one key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Right now, I have array sets like these:

```
[9] => Array
    (
        [sl] => 10
        [upload_dt] => 2015-04-15 14:39:58
        [total_files] => 3
        [file_name] => logo01.png
        [remarks] => qqq
        [status] => pending
        [download_file] => http://localhost/web/download_file21
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [sl] => 10
        [upload_dt] => 2015-04-15 14:39:58
        [total_files] => 3
        [file_name] => face.jpg
        [remarks] => 5645645
        [status] => pending
        [download_file] => http://localhost/web/download_file22
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [sl] => 10
        [upload_dt] => 2015-04-15 14:39:58
        [total_files] => 3
        [file_name] => ID_11401871809904(15).pdf
        [remarks] => 567567
        [status] => pending
        [download_file] => http://localhost/web/download_file23
    )
```

Now, I need to merge same values in some of the indices into one arrays.

The merged array values should look like this in the end.

```
[9] => Array
    (
        [sl] => 10
        [upload_dt] => 2015-04-15 14:39:58
        [total_files] => 3
        [file_name] => logo01.png , face.jpg, ID_11401871809904(15).pdf
        [remarks] => qqq, 5645645 , 567567
        [status] => pending, pending ,pending
        [download_file] => http://localhost/web/download_file21,
                           http://localhost/web/download_file22,
                       http://localhost/web/download_file23
    )
```

Now, I tried using `array_merge` but it didn't actually work in this case.

Comment: Simply use array_merge

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i have tried its not working

Comment: do u need to tuple array elements that have s1 value in common? u had to state this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually merging strings inside those arrays so just ditch the `array_merge` idea, and just use a simple loop then use the key as your basis to concatenate strings. Rough example:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    if(!isset($result[$values['sl']])) {
        $result[$values['sl']] = $values; // initial
    } else {
        foreach(array('file_name', 'remarks', 'status', 'download_file') as $field) {
            $result[$values['sl']][$field] .= ", {$values[$field]}";
        }

    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZN7mQL)

Comment: why you just copied my answer.

Comment: @ShikhaSinghal excuse me? copied your answer? why would i even do that

Comment: @Ghost but i am getting empty arrays before getting the output

Comment: @dude what do you mean empty arrays? i'm just the data that you provided, check the sample output. its the same from the above data. unless the one you're using is really different from the one posted

Answer (score 2):

Solution will be like this:

```
<?php
    $result = array();
    $ar1[9] = Array
                (
                    'sl' => 10,
                    'upload_dt' => '2015-04-15 14:39:58',
                    'total_files' => 3,
                    'file_name' => 'logo01.png',
                    'remarks' => 'qqq',
                    'status' => 'pending',
                    'download_file' => 'http://localhost/web/download_file21'
                );
    $ar1[10] = Array
                (
                    'sl' => 10,
                    'upload_dt' => '2015-04-15 14:39:58',
                    'total_files' => 3,
                    'file_name' => 'face.jpg',
                    'remarks' => '5645645',
                    'status' => 'pending',
                    'download_file' => 'http://localhost/web/download_file22'
                );

    $ar1[11] =  Array
                (
                    'sl' => 10,
                    'upload_dt' => '2015-04-15 14:39:58',
                    'total_files' => 3,
                    'file_name' => 'ID_11401871809904(15).pdf',
                    'remarks' => 567567,
                    'status' => 'pending',
                    'download_file' => 'http://localhost/web/download_file23'
                );

    foreach($ar1 as $record){
        $keys = array_keys($record); 
        foreach($keys as $key) { 
            if(array_key_exists($key,$result)){
                $valeInKey = explode(',', $result[$key]);
                if (!in_array($record[$key], $valeInKey)){
                    $result[$key]= $result[$key] .",".$record[$key];
                }
            } else{
                $result[$key]= $record[$key];
            } 
        }

    }
    echo"<pre>";print_r($result);exit;

    ?>
```

Comment: its a single array not multiple arrays

Comment: You can change the format as you want. Like :                                  $ar1 =array(
  9 => Array
            (
              --------------------
            ),
   10 =>  Array
            (
               --------------------
            ),
   11 =>  Array
            (
                --------------------
            )
  
 );

Answer (score 0):

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) won't work, because the keys would overwrite each other.
A solution would be to merge them with a the help of a foreach. Something like this:

```
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key] .= ", ".$value;
}
```

But you would have multiple entries for every single array you want to merge. If you just want to have them for a few, you have to check the key and do something accordingly.

Comment: or even foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key][] = $value;
}, then foreach $new -> arrayUNIQUE() -> implode.(', ').. u g4 th idea!